# How do the Dragon and Monster Packs affect Monster Deck size?

Tags: margraves-of-valeria

There are two [bonus packs](https://www.dailymagicgames.com/shop/r4d8jt0lct34aafzdo8zs8ojz7vfm3) which affect the monster decks in [Margraves of Valeria](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BZOZMSg_AaWz0eRBVQPhU5VfCJ3wjDXx/view).

Are they purely additive, to the original monster decks? That would be a 40% increase in deck size, so it seems extreme to me, but maybe it's balanced to account for that?

(The [Monster Pack rules](https://s3.amazonaws.com/geekdo-files.com/bgg274670?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22Margraves_Monster_Pack.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJYFNCT7FKCE4O6TA%2F20201208%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201208T200420Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=45597d39f62361d08c9aaa7499b754e7955ca3adfbf59df8770ca38be0e5d8f0) note to "just shuffle them into the four Monster cards above the Lair card in each monster stack". And the dragon rules, which are not online, also don't mention removing anything.)

Alternatively, should some original monsters be removed, when playing with at least one of these packs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, they're additive.

The event pack is purely additive explicitly, lending further support for this interpretation of the monster pack(s).

Also the dragon banner is confirmed additive in this [BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2452109/dragons-pack-new-dragon-banner-scoring-question), lending further support for the idea.

As to whether they have been balanced for that, well, that's a subjective call. In some cases, the questions of balance either don't come up or are not sufficiently weighted against other questions of marketing and so on. Whether that's the case here I cannot say.